# my jsp doesn't see css

Tags: html, css, jsp, tomcat

My project structure:

[image: folders]

hello.jsp:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/myStyle.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Text</h1>
<p>Text.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

myStyle.css:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana,  sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    color: #333;
}
h1 {
    color: #a52a2a;
    font-size: 24pt;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}
p {
    text-align: justify;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Could someone please explain me why css doesn't work?
I use Intellij IDEA as IDE and Tomcat.

This works though:

```
<style>
        <%@include file="/resources/myStyle.css" %>
</style>
```

Comment: View source in browser, see what you're actually printing into your `link href` and figure out whether that is the proper relative path from your url.

Comment: Post your mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml where you have defined your resources mapping.

Comment: The problem was in mvc-dispatcher-servlet. I needed to add this:
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try with any one. All these are **relative path** with respect to `webapp` folder.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/myStyle.css" >
```

OR

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
                href="<%=application.getContextPath() %>/resources/myStyle.css" >
```

OR

```
<jsp:directive.include file="/resources/myStyle.css" />
```

---

**JSP - The include Directive**

The filename in the include directive is actually a **relative URL**. If you just specify a filename with no associated path, the JSP compiler assumes that the file is in the same directory as your JSP.

The include directive is used to includes a file during the **translation phase**. This directive tells the container to merge the content of other external files with the current JSP during the translation phase. You may code include directives anywhere in your JSP page.

Comment: I did this:
<style>
        <%@include file="/resources/myStyle.css" %>
</style>
and it worked. What could be the problem?

Comment: Check it in Firefox Firebug plugin that css has been loaded or not.

Comment: Have a look at the sample code on [JSP - The include Directive](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/include_directive.htm) to know more about it.

Comment: @user2246018 This is all about the **relative path** from the webapp folder if you start the url with a forward slash `/`

Comment: <jsp:directive.include file="/resources/myStyle.css" />
with this i just see in the browser the text of my css file

Comment: Do you know what is the difference between `<jsp:directive` and `<%@include`? If not then look at link shared in my above comments.

Comment: Ok, I see. But it still doesn't explain why it works with "style" tag and doesn't work without it.

Comment: I don't think so that `<style>` is required at all. `<style>` is used to define custom CSS in JSP itself.